# Validate text box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, requiredfieldvalidator

I have several asp text box inside my aspx page. And there is no enough space to show Requred field validator messages. Is there any solution to this? using jquery or something else?

Comment: check out my answer. It will surely help you. you don't have to write a single line of extra code. just few few properties, and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply highlight the text-box with `Red` border to mark that their is an issue with the text-box data.

You can use CSS like this:

```
input.error  
{ 
   background: Yellow; border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

On error, just add the class to the `input` and also input tooltip

```
$("input").addClass("error").attr('title', 'An error occurred!');
```

Comment: Can you please explain more on this?

Comment: See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cPcFH/) that I have created. Everything is pretty self-explanatory here. Also, feel free to ask any question you have!

Comment: textbox will be marked as red border, fine. But how a user should know which causes this red border? Not a proper solution.

Comment: @CodeRider We could do attr('placeholder','Data not given');

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
$(":text").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==""){
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    alert($(this).attr("id") & " validate error");  
    return
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both javascript or jQuery, by validate data and then turn back your message in to the input if it is not validated.
ex:

```
if($('#idOfFeild').val()==''){
    $('#idOfFeild').val('Please input your data');
}
```

You can add style too to warn your users!

Answer (score 1):

You can read this article :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43772/Generic-Code-of-Validating-Fields-with-Jquery and them try this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   function callOnload()
   {
      $("input[isvalidate=true]").each(
                              function(n)
                              {
                                 $('#' +this.id).addClass('mandatory');
                                 this.onkeyup=function()
                                 {
                                    if(this.value==='')
                                    {
                                       $('#' +this.id).removeClass('normal');
                                       $('#' +this.id).addClass('mandatory');
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                       $('#' +this.id).removeClass('mandatory');
                                       $('#' +this.id).addClass('normal');
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                        );

         $("#btnSubmit").click(
                              function()
                              {
                                  $("input[isvalidate=true]").each(
                                  function(n)
                                  {
                                     if(this.value==='')
                                     {
                                        alert($('#' +this.id).attr('errprMsg'));
                                     }
                                  }
                                 );
                                return false;
                              }
                           );
   }
   $(document).ready(callOnload);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes obviously, you have a very simple solution.

you don't have to use any jquery stuff. you just have to use `asp:validationSummary`.

I'm posting here solution. with this you can show all error messages in simple popup by using standard asp `validation controls`.  It won't consume any space on your `page`.

Have a look on code below:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="validation1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true"  ShowSummary="false" DisplayMode="SingleParagraph" ValidationGroup="abc" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAge" Display="None" ValidationGroup="abc" ErrorMessage="Field Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 <asp:Button ID="btn" Text="click"  runat="server" ValidationGroup="abc" />
```

Here i have set `ShowMessageBox="true"` in `Validation Summary`, which will show all error messages in popup.

Set your validators `Display="none"`, so that the error messages display only in the popup.

the error message will look like below image. You don't have to worry about to manage space of page.

[image]

It is perfect , easy and simple solution for your problem.

Let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: Message box and alert box can't be included in my project.

Comment: why you can't include it in project?

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly to alert() you can use your own validator and color text or textbox.
I have got small example on my page and you can adapt it. Add css class:
http://kjinit.blogspot.com/2013/03/jquery-dynamic-adding-css-class.html
and remove css class.

Of course first you need to validate it like this: if('#yourInputId').val('');
Just color your text adding or removing css class when it is correct or not.